# How can I use full citations in footnotes using natbib, chicago style?

Tags: citing, natbib, chicago-style, bibentry

I tried using the `bibentry` package as many people mention on here, but for some reason it will not work with chicago style. I am using BibDesk with a bbl bibliography.

This is what my header looks like right now:

```
\documentclass[11pt,notitlepage]{article}       
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath, booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{breaklines=true}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{layouts} 
\setlength{\parindent}{.5in}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpg,.png}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\doublespacing
```

And then in the footer I have:

```
\newpage
\bibliography{DSP} 
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\end{document}
```

When I try to use `\footnote{\bibentry{key}}` I get the following warning:

!Paragraph ended before \citeauthoryear was complete.  \par

I get the same warning if I just use `\bibentry{key}`. These warnings go away when I change my bibliography style to "plain" but it still doesn't work the way I want it to--the footnotes are there, but they are all blank and none of my other citations appear. It'll just say (author?) or (year?) or (citation?) in place of my current cites.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to use a bibliography style that is compatible with `natbib`. Instead if `plain` you can use `plainnat`.

Comment: Not directly related to the immediate topic of your posting, but probably helpful for your long-term ability to use LaTeX effectively: You currently load a lot of packages; several of them are loaded not once but twice, while for others you should load one or the other package *but not both*. Do yourself a favor and go through the many `\usepackage` statements and cull the ones you don't use. The payoff will be a dramatically increased ability to understand what the one's you keep actually accomplish and thus why they should continue to be loaded.

Comment: @Guido -- `plain` *is* compatible with `natbib`; one just can't produce authoryear-style citations with it.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific as to what you mean by "Chicago style"? Do you mean authoryear-style citations (which is more commonly known as "Harvard style"), or do you mean the distinctive formatting guidelines set forth in the "Chicago Manual of Style"? Note that neither the `plain` nor the `plainnat` bibliography styles are meant to create Chicago-formatted references.